# C++ - 'class' type redefinition

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

I made a smaller reproducible version of the code that gave me these errosr: `'MyNamespace::MySecondClass': 'class' type redefinition`, `'print': is not a member of 'MyNamespace::MySecondClass'`. Is there any way of working around this problem?

```cpp
// MyClass.h

#pragma once

namespace MyNamespace {

    class MySecondClass {};

}

// MyClass.cpp

#include "MyClass.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyNamespace::MySecondClass
{
public:
    void print(const char* msg)
    {
        cout << msg << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: `class MySecondClass {};` should be `class MySecondClass;`

Comment: In addition to Alan: `namespace MyNS { class MyClass; }` is an incomplete type aka a forward declaration. (This would fix your issue.) But with braces: `namespace MyNS { class MyClass { }; }` it becomes a complete type. Now, `class MyNS::MyClass { void print(); };` redefines the previous complete (class) type which is prohibited.

Comment: There seems to be a general mis-understanding. `MyClass.h` and `MyClass.cpp` let me think you want something like interface and implementation. So, the header should provide the class definition with full declaration `namespace MyNS { class MyClass { void print(); }; }` while `MyClass.cpp` provides the implementation: `void MyNS::MyClass::print() { std::cout << "anything"; }` or `namespace MyNS { void MyClass::print() { std::cout << "anything"; } }`.

Comment: If you instead intend to hide declaration details of `MyNS::MyClass` (what I could imagine alternatively) then have a look for the [PImpl idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in `MyClass.h` you define a class `MySecondClass` as an empty class.  When you the define your class  in MyClass.cpp you give a different definition, which contains some new members. This infringes the One Definition Rule (ODR).

### Solution 1

remove `{}` in the header. This will tell the compiler that you declare that such a class exists but that it will be defined later. Your code would compile. Unfortunately if you’d include the header in other cpp, these could make only a very very limited use of `MySecondClass`.

### Solution 2

define in the header the class with all its members (but without providing the implementation of the member functions:the signature is sufficient). This would allow the class to be used in whichever cpp that
would include it:

```
// MyClass.h
#pragma once
namespace MyNamespace {
    class MySecondClass {
    public:
        void print(const char* msg);
    };
}
```

You’d then define the members of the class in its cpp in the appropriate namespace:

```
// MyClass.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClass.h"

using namespace std;

namespace MyNamespace {
    // member functions
    void MySecondClass::print(const char* msg)
    {
        cout << msg << endl;
    }
}
```

Remark: the include sequence in the cpp should first include the standard library headers, then only your own headers. It makes no difference in your simple example, but  better get used the good practices immediately.

Comment: One problem though. When I want to make a derived class, declare it in the header and define it in the cpp file, it gives me an error. `class or struct definition missing`

Comment: @PhysicalExperience could you post the code with the derived class as a separate question, if you don’t find similar questions related to namespace and derived classes ?